# How can I get the assumed screen resolution of Java2D?

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I'm using Swing and Java2D on a Windows 7 machine with Java 8 and have issues with my fonts in java being rendered much smaller than they should given their font size and my screen resolution.

According to [this old article](http://www.3rd-evolution.de/tkrammer/docs/java_font_size.html) the reason might be a difference between my screen resolution and the assumed screen resolution of Java2D. The author Thomas Krammer suggests the following workaround:

```java
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    int screenRes = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();
    int fontSize = (int)Math.round(12.0 * screenRes / 72.0);

    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);

    g2d.setFont(font);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.drawString("Hello World", 25, 100);
}
```

This seems to work well in my case. However, I would very much like to avoid hard-coding the 72 dpi into my program but instead get this from where it originates.

Does anyone have an idea on how to get this *assumed resolution* from Java2D?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
minimal working example:

```
package fontmagic;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FontMagic
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Font Magic");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label = new JLabel("This is Text with a font size.");

    frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
  } 
}
```

This code generates text that is 9 pixels high on my screen.

When I write text in MS Office, Libre Office or Scribus with Arial, 12pt and scale it to 100%, the result is 12 pixels in height on the screen.

Surprisingly I just found out, that text in gimp with Arial, 12pt also results in 9 pixels height. So maybe this isn't a Java problem at all?

Comment: On which version of Windows is this happening?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. Added the information to the question in case this is important.

Comment: And you’re saying that if you want a 12 point font, `new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12)` does not provide that?

Comment: Yes that's correct. It provides something that looks more like 9pt to me when compared with MS Word 2010 or Scribus. I understand that the Font size in pt must be converted into px somehow and that's exactly what the screen resolution is for. As a system variable, however, this should be the same for all Programms running on my computer.

Comment: Java2D already accounts for the screen resolution.  What you are seeing is not normal, and you definitely should not need to compensate for it by doing your own math.  Can you create a [mcve], both to give us a way to observe your issue, and to verify that no other code is affecting what you’re seeing?

Comment: I added an example. Obviously, I don't even need Java2D, which is why I removed the tag from the question.
I am also quite unsure now, how much this problem is even a java one. Would it be better to reword the question or shall I delete it and post it to a more fitting SE site?